# Writing a cmd/powershell script to automate installation of CUDA and intergrating it for another application. How to set perm enviromentals

Tags: powershell

There are certain modules in the application Pixinsight that are AI and can utilize the GPU to make them much faster.  To utilize this, the process of installing CUda intigratng it into Pixinsight is long and can be confusing.  Download 3 CUDA and a couple of library zip files. Installation of CUDA, unzipping the library zip files and placing the library/dll cells in different folders, and then requires the setting of some permanent windows path enviromentals for cuda.

I know how to do everything except the scripting of setting those enviromentals.  I found how to launch powershell as administrator which then can be used to set these enviromentals. But, is there anyway to run from a command line of powershell as administrator.  I am trying to remove all manual steps other then launching the script.

Here are the steps that I want to script. https://pixinsight.com/forum/index.php?threads/up-to-date-instructions-for-enabling-gpu-acceleration.20275/

I do understand the security conserns, and if it can't be done.  Then it can't be done.

I was going to restrict this to Windows 10 and Windows 11.

I have set enviromentals with a command line powershell, but when powershell exits.  Then the enviromentals are gone.

I have launched the powershell gui from commmand line with -Verb runAs, but unless I can pass the commands to that gui.  There is still a requirement for manual entry.